# Worksheet_Change trouble working on multiple columns

Tags: excel, vba

i have trouble getting this code to work on the last to columns (T and U) 
what can i do to change tis?

code:

```
   Private Sub Worksheet_ChangeS(ByVal Target As Range) 'column s, structure
    If Intersect(Target, Range("S:S")) Is Nothing Then Exit Sub
    Dim foundVal As Range
    Set foundVal = Sheets("Dropdown").Range("A:A").Find(Target, LookIn:=xlValues, lookat:=xlWhole)
    If Not foundVal Is Nothing Then
        Target = foundVal.Offset(0, 1)
    End If
End Sub

Private Sub Worksheet_ChangeT(ByVal Target As Range) 'column t, component
    If Intersect(Target, Range("T:T")) Is Nothing Then Exit Sub
    Dim foundVal As Range
    Set foundVal = Sheets("Dropdown").Range("D:D").Find(Target, LookIn:=xlValues, lookat:=xlWhole)
    If Not foundVal Is Nothing Then
        Target = foundVal.Offset(0, 1)
    End If
End Sub

Private Sub Worksheet_ChangeU(ByVal Target As Range) 'column U, parameter
    If Intersect(Target, Range("U:U")) Is Nothing Then Exit Sub
    Dim foundVal As Range
    Set foundVal = Sheets("Dropdown").Range("I:I").Find(Target, LookIn:=xlValues, lookat:=xlWhole)
    If Not foundVal Is Nothing Then
        Target = foundVal.Offset(0, 1)
    End If
End Sub
```

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There's only one [Worksheet_Change](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/excel.worksheet.change) event that fires whenever a cell is changed.

`Private Sub Worksheet_ChangeS(ByVal Target As Range)` would have to be "manually" called from the `Worksheet_Change` event to work as it's a user defined procedure.

You should delete those three procedures and using something along the lines of:

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)

    Dim lCol As Long
    Dim foundVal As Range

    Application.EnableEvents = False

    If Not Intersect(Target, Range("S:U")) Is Nothing Then

        If Target.Cells.Count = 1 Then 'Check a single cell is changing.
            Select Case Target.Column
                Case 19 'col S
                    lCol = 1
                Case 20 'col T
                    lCol = 4
                Case 21 'col U
                    lCol = 9
            End Select

            Set foundVal = Worksheets("DropDown").Columns(lCol).Find( _
                Target.Value, LookIn:=xlValues, LookAt:=xlWhole)

            If Not foundVal Is Nothing Then
                Target = foundVal.Offset(, 1)
            End If
        End If
    End If

    Application.EnableEvents = True

End Sub
```

Although looking at the range you then try and use `FIND` on you should be able to offset from the Target column and do the find in a single statement rather than three.

**Edit:**
I've updated the code to include `EnableEvents`.  At the end of your code you change the value of `Target` which would cause the `Worksheet_Change` event to fire again.  `EnableEvents` stops that from happening.

**Edit 2:**
I've updated the code to use a single `FIND`.  The `Select Case` gives the column to search in the `FIND` command.

**Note:**
If your code crashes for any reason you may need to open the immediate window (`Ctrl+G`) and type in `Application.EnableEvents = True` as this does not reset when the code stops - you'll just notice that all your event code stops firing.

Comment: When deleting a row in the sheet, it gives an 1004 error pointing at the [set foundval]area.. Can you explain why?

Comment: The only error that jumps out at me would be that by deleting an entire row, or column would mean you're working on more than one cell - the `FIND` command excepts a single value.  I've updated the code to make sure the `Change` event only fires when a single cell is changed.